# Websocket server starts running, then stops. Running start_server from inside of asyncio.ensure_future

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am working on a streaming application and I am somewhat new to websockets and asyncio. Here is the use case I am after:

I have a number of different websocket connections receiving data from different sources. When a message arrives from any source, I standardize it, and write it to a database. On another machine, which has GPU compute, I have a websocket server running to accept connections. I want the source streams to connect to my GPU machine and send messages there in addition to the database.

The code running on my non-GPU server looks like this:

```
class SourceStream():

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.db = client.connect().db

    async def watch_source(self):
        async for source_websocket in websockets.connect("ws://some-source-data"):
            try:
                async for message in source_websocket:
                    await self.queue.put(self.process(message))
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                print("Connection closed. Trying again.")

    async def process(self, message):
        """Do stuff"""
        return processed_messege

    async def handle_message(self):
        async for gpu_websocket in websockets.connect("ws://my-gpu-server"):
            while True:
                message = await self.queue.get()
                await gpu_websocket.send(message)
                await self.db.write(message)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(SourceStream().watch_source())
asyncio.ensure_future(SourceStream().handle_message())
loop.run_forever()
```

The code running on my GPU server looks like this:

```
class AggregationStream():

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.df = cudf.DataFrame()
        self.db = client.connect().db
        self.last_agg = datetime.utcnow()

    async def start_server(self):
        async with websockets.serve(self.stream_handler, "", 8001):
            await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

    async def stream_handler(self, websocket):
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            chunk = cudf.DataFrame(json.loads(message))
            print(chunk)
            await self.queue.put(chunk)

    async def aggregate(self):
        while True:
            chunk = await self.queue.get()
            self.df = self.df.append(chunk)
            if (datetime.utcnow() - self.last_agg) > timedelta(seconds=1):
                self.df = self.df.filter()
                aggregated_data = self.df.groupby().sum()
                self.db.write(aggregated_data)
                self.last_agg = datetime.utcnow()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(AggregationStream().start_server())
asyncio.ensure_future(AggregationStream().aggregate())
loop.run_forever()
```

This code works for a little while, but then I get an error that looks like this on the GPU server:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<AggregationStream.start_server() running at /path/aggregation.py:157> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f0eefda1cd0>()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object AggregationStream.start_server at 0x7f0eeff33c40>
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: sent 1001 (going away); then received 1001 (going away)
```

And connections close on the non-GPU server:

```
Connection closed. Trying again.
Connection closed. Trying again.
...
```

The problem goes away when I stop running the aggregation routine. If I modify the GPU server code to just do:

```
asyncio.run(AggregationStream().start_server())
```

then I can see chunks printing to the stream and the connections do not drop. Any ideas about what is going on here? Am I just missing an error in AggregationStream.aggregate()?

Comment: maybe you should use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed when t cruch. You could also remove `try/except` to see full error message. It may gives you some information which can explain what is the problem.

Comment: I've tried printing everything I can and everything looks fine as far as I can tell. I am reasonably confident that my websocket server is dropping all connections for some reason which is why I see that ConnectionClosedOK: sent 1001. I guess maybe a better question, is there anything inherently problematic about my strategy here? Is there any reason my server might stop, say maybe if some other task is taking too long in the event loop?

Comment: The part I'm really struggling to understand is why I don't see connections drop when using asyncio.run(), but do see them drop when i use asyncio.ensure_future(). I'm reasonably confident that there isn't any problem while I'm processing messages because I have been watching more or less the same code feed successfully into the database